# How to setup compatible code environment between VxWorks 5.5 and 6.x?

Tags: vxworks

We have an existing VxWorks 5.5 project and want to port it to VxWorks 6.6.
VxWorks 6.x has a bunch of new capabilities (MMU, RTPs, etc...) which we don't want to use at this point since it would complicate the porting effort.

How do we specify that we want a 5.5 compatible environment?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your VxWorks project, you can specify the PROFILE_COMPATIBLE which creates a 5.5 compatible environment.

In workbench, this is done in the new project creation dialog.  It is the 3rd or 4th dialog screen titled "Configuration Profile"

When creating a project from the command line with vxprj, simply add a "-profile PROFILE_COMPATIBLE" parameter.